# Why was the doctor left alive in the bus?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-2018

In *Halloween* (2018), the bus carrying Myers and his doctor (Dr. Ranbir Sartain) crashes. The guard and driver are found dead (presumably killed by Myers), but the doctor is alive and well inside the bus.

**Why did Myers leave the doctor alive?**

Comment: My conclusion is that Michael most likely thought the doctor was dead. At first, I can see why this would encourage you to believe that the doctor was the one who caused the crash, as in your other question. However, even if he did, he's still left in the bus with Michael; would Michael just leave him alive as a thank you? I think the doctor **should** be in as much danger either way. Michael is supposed to be unfathomably indiscriminate in his kills. Also, the doctor could have escaped. Michael's not much of a runner. Hope this doesn't sound like criticism, just thoughts -- good question!

Comment: It makes little sense he's on that bus in the first place, so basically this is a case of a writer adding ridiculous elements because "the story requires it": they need Sartain later on as an additional baddie to "protect" and help Myers, hence this rather illogical event. Then again, Sartain isn't a threat to Myers after the bus accident, whereas the guard was (assuming the driver was killed when Myers attacked him).

Comment: There's also this: ["I'm pretty sure the cop, that the boy finds on the side of the road next to the bus, has thin slash marks along his neck. Similar to the neck wounds that Hawkins had after Sartain used the pen knife against Hawkins."](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/9qgsj6/halloween_2018_spoilers_when_did_dr_sartain_or/e89pax3/) So perhaps Sartain aided Myers in his escape, something that would only be noticed by eagle-eyed viewers?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Nothing about this is ridiculous really. It makes *a lot* of sense that he's on the bus actually. He *had* to be on the bus in order to get Michael free. This was his last chance to learn something about Michael before he was going to be locked up forever. That wasn't the "story requiring" the doctor to be there for later. It was the *doctor* himself requiring to be there to save his life's entire work. And regarding external plausibility, there isn't really anything too hard to believe for the doctor to construe in order to justify accompanying his patient to the other guards either